# What's wrong with this dealloc in ARC?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread

I am working on an app that does image processing and displays the resulting image. Im using `UIScrollView` to let user scroll all images, because the image is not a standard jpg or png, it takes time to load. I use GCD to load asynchronously, when finished dispatch to main queue to display. the snippet is as follows:

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)name
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = [Reader loadImage:name];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self displayImage:image];
        });
    });
}
```

the `loadImage` method of Reader is like this:

```
+ (UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)name
{
   UInt8 *data = NULL;
   NSString *mfjPath = [TMP stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
   NSData *mfjData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mfjPath];
   if(mfjData){
        data = malloc(sizeof(UInt8)*mfjData.length);
        [mfjData getBytes:data];
   }
   if(data){
        ResultHolder *result = [sDecoder decodeData:data withOffset:0];// static id<IDecoder> sDecoder; in Reader.m before @implementation Reader.
        return [result bitmap];
   }
    retun nil;
}
```

`IDCoder` is a protocol which is

```
@protocol IDecoder <NSObject>
- (ResultHolder *)decodeData:(UInt8 *) withOffset:(int)offset;
@end
```

`ResultHolder` is a class to load simple image and combine complicated image. which is as follows:

ResultHolder.h

```
typedef struct color24{
    UInt8 R;
    UInt8 G;
    UInt8 B;
} Color24;

@interface ResultHolder : NSObject
{
    unsigned long mWidth;
    unsigned long mHeight;
    UInt8 *mData;
    CGImageRef mBitmap;

    BOOL isMonoColor;
    Color24 mMonoColor;
}

+ (ResultHolder *)resultHolderWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image;
+ (ResultHolder *)resultHolderWithData:(UInt8 *)data Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height;
+ (ResultHolder *)resultHolderWithMonoColor:(Color24)monoColor withWidth:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height;

- (ResultHolder *)initWithData:(UInt8 *)data Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long) height;
- (ResultHolder *)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image;
- (ResultHolder *)initWithMonoColor:(Color24)monoColor withWidth:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height;

- (BOOL)isSuccess;
- (UIImage *)bitmap;
- (void)combineFixResultHolder:(ResultHolder *)child Rect:(CGRect)bounds Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height;
- (void)combineResultHolder:(ResultHolder *)child Bounds:(CGRect)bounds Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height;
@end
```

ResultHolder.m

```
@implementation ResultHolder

@synthesize width = mWidth;
@synthesize height = mHeight;
@synthesize isMonoColor;
@synthesize monoColor = mMonoColor;

- (ResultHolder *)initWithData:(UInt8 *)data Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height
{

    if (self = [super init]) {        
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mData = malloc(mWidth*mHeight*sizeof(Color24));
        memcpy(mData, data, mWidth*mHeight*sizeof(Color24));

        mBitmap = NULL;
    }

    return self;
}

- (ResultHolder *)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        mBitmap = CGImageRetain(image);
        mWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image);
        mHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image);
    }
    return self;
}

- (ResultHolder *)initWithMonoColor:(Color24)monoColor withWidth:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        mMonoColor = monoColor;

        isMonoColor = YES;
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mBitmap = NULL;
        mData = NULL;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (ResultHolder *)resultHolderWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
    ResultHolder *resultHolder = [[ResultHolder alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
    return resultHolder;
}

+ (ResultHolder *)resultHolderWithData:(UInt8 *)data Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height
{
    ResultHolder *resultHolder = [[ResultHolder alloc] initWithData:data Width:width andHeight:height];
    return resultHolder;
}

+ (ResultHolder *)resultHolderWithMonoColor:(Color24)monoColor withWidth:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height
{
    ResultHolder *resultHolder = [[ResultHolder alloc] initWithMonoColor:monoColor withWidth:width andHeight:height];
    return resultHolder;
}

- (BOOL)isSuccess
{
    if ([ReaderConfigures CodecDebug])
        NSLog(@"ResultHolder isSuccess");
    return (mData != NULL || isMonoColor || mBitmap != nil);
}

- (void)fillMonoColor
{

    if (isMonoColor) {
        if (mData) {
            free(mData);
        }
        mData = (UInt8 *)malloc(mWidth*mHeight*sizeof(Color24));

        for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
                memcpy(mData+(i*mWidth+j)*3, &mMonoColor, sizeof(Color24));
            }
        }
        isMonoColor = NO;
    }
}


- (void)extractBitmap  
{
    if (mBitmap) {

        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(mBitmap);
        CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
        UInt8 * dataSource = (UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);

        size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(mBitmap);
        size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(mBitmap);
        if(mData)
            free(mData);
        mData = malloc(width*height*3);

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                memcpy(mData+(i*width+j)*3, dataSource+(i*width+j)*4, sizeof(Color24));
            }
        }

        CFRelease(bitmapData);
        CGImageRelease(mBitmap);
        mBitmap = NULL;
    }
}


- (UInt8 *)getRawData
{

    if (mBitmap) {
        [self extractBitmap];
    }
    if (isMonoColor) {
        [self fillMonoColor];
    }

    return mData;
}

- (UIImage *)bitmap
{
    if (mBitmap) {
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:mBitmap];
        CGImageRelease(mBitmap);
        mBitmap = NULL;
        return image; 
    }
    if (isMonoColor) {
        [self fillMonoColor];
    }
    if (mData) {
        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, mData, mWidth*mHeight*3, NULL);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGImageRef bitmap = CGImageCreate(mWidth, mHeight, 8, 24, mWidth*3, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, dataProvider, NULL, YES, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:bitmap];
        CGImageRelease(bitmap);

        return image;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)combineResultHolder:(ResultHolder *) child Bounds:(CGRect) bounds Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(MAX(0, bounds.origin.x), MAX(0, bounds.origin.y),MIN(width - 1, bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width), MIN(height - 1, bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height));

    int w = MIN(rect.size.width + 1, child.width);
    int h = MIN(rect.size.height + 1, child.height);

    int dstPos = (height - 1 - (rect.origin.y + h - 1))*width;

    UInt8 *dataParent = [self getRawData];

    if (child.isMonoColor) {
        Color24 childMonoColor = child.monoColor;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            memcpy(dataParent+(dstPos+(int)rect.origin.x)*3, &childMonoColor, w*3);
            dstPos += width;
        }

    } else {
        UInt8 *dataChild = [child getRawData];
        if (dataChild != nil) {
            int srcPos = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                memcpy(dataParent+dstPos*3+((int)rect.origin.x)*3, dataChild+srcPos*3, w*3);
                srcPos += child.width;
                dstPos += width;
            }
        }

    }

}

- (void)combineFixResultHolder:(ResultHolder *)child Rect:(CGRect)bounds Width:(unsigned long)width andHeight:(unsigned long)height
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, height-1-bounds.origin.y-bounds.size.height, bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width, height-1-bounds.origin.y);

    [self combineResultHolder:child Bounds:rect Width:width andHeight:height];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (mData) {
        free(mData);
        mData = NULL;
    }
    if (mBitmap) {
        CGImageRelease(mBitmap);
        mBitmap = NULL;
    }
}

@end
```

for simple image, for example JPEG image only,  `+ (ResultHolder *)resultHolderWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image;` and `- (UIImage *)bitmap;` methods are called. for some complicated ones, 
`ResultHolder` will extract `mBitmap` to `mData`, and then combine with sub `resultHolder`'s `mData` to get the image. these methods work well if I load image in my main thread, but if I use GCD or `NSThread` to load image in background it is easy to crash, especially when loading complicated ones in background. when the app crashes, the main thread state a CGSConvertBGR888toRGBA8888 method error, one of other threads is running the `[ResultHolder dealloc]` method, actually is `free(mData)`. It seems there is a memory conflict between the loading thread and the main thread.

when the app crashes, the error is like this:
[image]

I have struggled for this bug for days, but still cannot find how to fix it.
I do hope someone can help me.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE:
I make a demo project [ReaderDemo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/psh08sijm4m4jd7/ReaderDemo.zip) to simulate the situation. If you are interested, you can download to see the error. There are 15 images in this project, the 5,7,14 images will cause the crash when scrolling, they are a little complicated than others. but if you scroll through thumbnail scrollview then click, they all can be displayed.

Comment: Is this code something you could put in a demo project and post to Dropbox public folder? Would be easier to debug code than reading through it.

Comment: @DavidH I update the question and add a link to the demo project.Thanks for your suggestion.you have helped me a lot. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: OK - I redownloaded, got the crash on my iPad so that's good. One note: the reason CGSConvertBGR888toRGBA8888 () is called is since you are giving the system images as BGR but it needs RGBA. So this is a huge waste of time, and you need to change the way you create images to be in the native order of the iPad/iPhone/armv7 - it will make your app much faster (as huge image conversion takes up lots of CPU).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems but lets start off with the first I found:

1. Improper test

   ```
   if (index > [mPageNames count]) {
   ```

   That needs to be >= or you crash.
2. you are calling dispatch_sync on the mainQueue, that does not seem to be a good decision (but maybe you have a really good one) - I changed it to async, seems to work OK
3. If you enable exceptions in this project it will really help you. Click the Break Points button in the Xcode toolbar. Then select the BreakPoints option left pane, second from the right. Tap the bottom left '+' icon and add an All Exceptions breakpoint. Now when you run the debugger stops where the problem occurrs.
4. I got a final crash that I'll let you fix:

   ```
   2012-09-26 08:55:12.378 ReaderDemo[787:11303] MFJAtIndex index out of bounds,index:15,bounds:15
   2012-09-26 08:55:12.379 ReaderDemo[787:11303] *** Assertion failure in -[ImageScrollView showLoadingForMFJ:], /Volumes/Data/Users/dhoerl/Downloads/ReaderDemo/ReaderDemo/ImageScrollView.m:247
   ```

This should get you on your way.

---

EDIT: Your problem relates to the management of the `mData` memory. You are trying to manage the lifecycle of it in your code, but this management is not sync'd with the `CGImageDataProvider` that is trying to use it. The crash is almost for sure (meaning I'm 99.99% convinced) a byproduct of the `CGImageProvided` created by `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` trying to access the data after your class has freed that memory in dealloc. I have had similar experiences with data providers.

The proper solution is to remove all `free(data)` calls, or at least most of them. Given the current structure of your code you will need to think about this carefully - you may want to replaced all the tests and malloc/frees with a flag. In the end, what you want to do is once the memory pointer is handed ovdr to `CGDataProviderCreateWithData`, you need to `NULL` out `mData` and let the data provider handle the removal.

The way to do this is to provide a function pointer to `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` in the past parameter:

```
CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback
A callback function that releases data you supply to the function CGDataProviderCreateWithData.

typedef void (*CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback) (
   void *info,
   const void *data,
   size_t size
);
```

All that function needs to do is just call `free(data);`. So whenever the data provider is done with the allocated memory, it will free it (and you don't need to worry about it).

Comment: I see,I usually test app on ipad2 not the simulator. when in ipad2, it will crashes as i said. But in simulator, it works well. as to 2), i use dispatch_sync in the dispatch_async block, its not in the mainQueue. 3) i have added one global Exception point,but it cannot give me much help. as to 4) I think there is some mistake in detecting the end when scrolling,I will fix it . So can you try to test it in ipad2? I do hope you can help me.

Comment: I'll be glad to test a new project on an iPad 3 (its all I have), but first I would ask you to fix the known bugs. There is no benefit to having that one block object block on messaging the main queue - it essentially goes away after the call, and since you are using a concurrent queue it doesn't block anything else. Its just makes it a bit harder for iOS to run your code. Think about it. Anyway, fix the problems so it all runs in the simulator, update your github project, I can look at it later today.

Comment: I have fixed the 4th bug, and update in my dropbox.You can download now,I will try to optimise the GCD as you said.I know ipad2 is an old one already. i will try to change a new project for ipad3.

Comment: The old one should run just fine - its just the retina images (which I don;t need to test). The iPad 3 has a second core so timing will be a bit different.

Comment: You save me again. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to free() or release your resources in any class in ARC enabled environment, you have to set proper flags for your class in 'Build Phases'. To do that, select your project file in XCode, select your target, go to 'Build Phases' section, find your class, and put `-fno-objc-arc` flag for that class. 
Or, maybe another reason, you are calling some CoreGraphics function that has to be called from main thread only in another thread.

Comment: yes, but i think you must manually free/release memory for Core Foundation classes and malloc in ARC.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. You can use `free()` and `CGImageRelease()` under ARC just fine.